# Scala nested for loop

Tags: scala, processing

I'm a new Scala fellow and using processing library in scala ,I have 2 questions here:

```
 val grid: Array[Cell] = Array()              
 val w = 60   
 val rows = height/w   
 val cols = width /w

 override def setup(): Unit = {  
   for(j <- 0 until rows;   
       i <- 0 until cols){   
   val cell = new Cell(i,j)   
   grid :+ cell   
   println(s"at row : $j, at col: $i") //it compiles only once (at row : 0, 
   }                                    //at col: 0 )                                          
}
override def draw(): Unit = {
  background(0)
  grid.foreach(cell => cell.display())//nothing happens
}
```

but if i replace the variables `rows` & `cols` by `height/w` & `width/w` in the nested loop as follows:

```
     for(j <- 0 until height/w;   
         i <- 0 until width/w){   
     val cell = new Cell(i,j)   
     grid :+ cell   
     println(s"at row : $j, at col: $i") //it compiles ordinary as nested 
        }                                 //for loop
```

the second question is in the class `Cell` here:

```
   class Cell(i: Int,j:Int){

     def display(): Unit = {
       val x = this.i * w
       val y = this.j * w

       println("it works")//doesn't work
       //creating a square
       stroke(255)
       line(x,y,x+w,y)//top
       line(x+w,y,x+x,y+w)//right
       line(x,y+w,x+w,y+w)//bottom
       line(x,y,x,y+w)//left

   }
 }
```

the method display doesn't work when calling at function `draw()` but no errors show up

Comment: Hi,
`Array()` in scala is unmutable. By doing `grid :+ cell` you just create a new Array with that value, but do not add this value to the grid array. You need to use `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Cell]()` instead and add the values using `+=`

Comment: Your loop looks good. I can assume that your height and width values are too small.

Comment: thanks dyrkin it really helped

Comment: Another way would be to use
`var grid: Array[Cell] = Array()`
and then 
`grid :+= cell`

Comment: "Array() in scala is unmutable" — to be more specific: on the JVM (including in Scala) an array is always a fixed size. They are otherwise mutable (that is, individual elements can be replaced).

Answer (score 1):

Use `tabulate` to initialise your `Array`:

```
val grid = Array.tabulate(rows * cols) { i => new Cell(i % cols, i / cols) }
```

If you still have a problem with the `display` function then please post it as a separate question.